# How to display Unicode UTF-8 as Unicode?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode

I have some UTF-8-encoded text files which display strange escape codes in Emacs. For instance, this text:

> In ista quaestione primo exponam quid intelligendum est per hoc nomen
>   ‘Deus’; secundo, respondebo ad quaestionem.

Shows like this in Emacs:

[image]

This only happens in Emacs. Other editors show the text correctly. How can I fix this problem?

---

**Update 1**

If I call `revert-buffer-with-coding-system` and select `utf-8` the file get read correctly. So, as Gilles has correctly guessed, Emacs isn't detecting the file encoding. If I add the code `; -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the file, Emacs opens and displays it correctly.

---

**Update 2**

I reencoded the file in "UTF-8 with BOM encoding," and now it displays alright in Emacs. I don't know what's the difference between the two types, but Emacs seems to be aware of the BOMed one only.

Comment: Emacs isn't recognizing the file as UTF-8. What is the content of your init file? What version of Emacs are you running? Does it change anything if you start Emacs with `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q`?

Comment: I have no problem with other UTF-8 files. I'm running GNU Emacs 24.4.4. No difference with `emacs -q` or `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Ah, if it works with other files and in a pristine configuration then the reason is probably that the file also contains invalid UTF-8 somewhere. Let me see how to tell with Emacs...

Comment: possibly related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/4100/2264

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some reason, Emacs isn't recognizing the file as UTF-8. 
You can force Emacs to reopen the file as UTF-8 by running the command `C-x RET r` ([`revert-buffer-with-coding-system`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specify-Coding.html#Specify-Coding)) and entering `utf-8`.

The reason why Emacs didn't recognize this file as UTF-8 (but recognizes other) is likely that it contains some invalid UTF-8 sequence. This sequence will still appear as backslash followed by three octal digits with a different color (the `escape-glyph` face) after reinterpreting the file as UTF-8. You can search for such a sequence by running `C-M-s` (`isearch-regexp`) and looking for

```
[^^@-~[:multibyte:]]
```

where `^@` is entered by typing `C-q C-SPC` (it's the character ^@ = 0, not the two-character sequence circumflex-at; the character before it is the circumflex character).

You can force Emacs to recognize the file as UTF-8 by adding a [coding system file variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specify-Coding.html#index-coding-1719): put something like `-*-coding: utf-8-*-` on the first line, or put something like this near the end of the file (you can replace `#` by any prefix, but `Local Variables:` and `End:` must appear exactly like this with the trailing colon):

```
# Local Variables:
# coding: utf-8
# End:
```

Emacs [chooses the encoding according to which files are interpreted](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html#Recognize-Coding) based on several settings, primarily [language environments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Language-Environments.html#Language-Environments) and the variables [`auto-coding-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recognize-Coding.html#index-auto_002dcoding_002dalist-1716) and `auto-coding-regexp-alist`. Since you have the same problem with this file even when running `emacs -Q`, I think that this isn't an issue with those settings, but with the file content.

Comment: If I open the file without the coding system file variable (i.e. when the file displays wrongly) and run the regex search, all of my `\342`, `\200`, `\230`, etc. get selected. But if I open it "correctly" (using the coding variable), then no search results appear.

Comment: @NVaughan Hmmm. Then I don't understand why this file isn't recognized as UTF-8 when others are (especially under `emacs -Q`).

Answer (score 2):

*For UNIX-like systems only.*

In many cases the straightforward encoding definition in ~/.bashrc ~/bash_profile

```
LANG=en_EN.UTF8
```

accomplished with

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

in ~/.profile should solve your issue.

*P.S. After these corrections you need to RELOGIN in your session to allow changes become visible.*

Comment: Althougth what you say may be useful, this does not appear to answer this question, since the problem was only with **some** utf-8 files.

Comment: Suppose that after the strict encoding definition in configuration files this problem might disappear for **all** files forever end ever :-)

Comment: Before I saw this answer, when I typed `C-h h` in emacs I saw lots and lots of `?????` instead of Unicode characters.  After I set the above `LC_ALL`, `LANG`, and `LANGUAGE` environment variables (and restarted emacs), entering `C-h h` showed me beautiful unicode renderings in my emacs instance.  (So I gotta say that this answer worked for me.)

Answer (score 2):

It's late to answer the question about the BOM, but I'll do it anyhow.

The byte order mark (BOM) is a sequence of three bytes \xef\xbb\xbf which, at the beginning of a file, indicates to systems and applications that the contents are encoded as UTF-8.  Properly they're metadata, not treated as part of the contents.

Most applications -- Emacs is one of them -- honor the BOM and write all UTF-8 files with it.  Other applications may honor it in reading, but not write it; and others don't know about it and may throw an error message when they encounter it.  In other words, the situation is messy.  I prefer to use it wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows

it started recognizing and displaying characters correctly by setting the environment variable suggested by @Alioth.

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```